# Install PyQt4 in Python 3 on mac

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, homebrew

I am trying to install PyQt4 on my mac. My python version is 3.6.3.

I've tried `Homebrew` to do that but it didn't work. The codes I used are as following in `Terminal`.

```
brew install qt
brew install sip --with-python3
brew install pyqt --with-python3
```

Also, I've set an path as following:

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

After running these installs, it does install PyQt on my mac but the version is `PyQt5`.  However, the version I want is `PyQt4`.

I've looked up all the similar questions here, but it all kinda out of date. If anyone knows how to solve this, please let me know. Appreciated!

Comment: Why not install from source? http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html

Comment: Qt 4 has been deprecated a long time ago; Homebrew won’t help you in installing it.

Comment: I actually have the same problem. If you found a solution, please share it! ;-)